# How to convert UIImage to byte array or base64encoding?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I have an image which i want to send as byte array to a server .I want to know how to convert uiimage to byte array ? I have to send parameter as

`<byteArrayIn>base64Binary</byteArrayIn>` to the web service

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
UIImage *img = ...;
CGFloat quality = 0.85;
NSData *jpegdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,quality);
```

or

```
NSData *pngdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function for iOS to convert from UIImage to byte array -->

```
+ (unsigned char*)UIImageToByteArray:(UIImage*)image; {

    unsigned char *imageData = (unsigned char*)(malloc( 4*image.size.width*image.size.height));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData,
                                                image.size.width,
                                                image.size.height,
                                                8,
                                                image.size.width*4,
                                                colorSpace,
                                                kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage( bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), imageRef);

    CGContextRelease( bitmap);
    CGImageRelease( imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace);

    return imageData;
}
```

once you have the byte array data, the algorithm for base64 encoding is easy to implement and you can read up on it on wikipedia.  There may be an easier way to base64 encode it as well I am not sure.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: This is an inefficient way for several reasons. UIImagePNGRepresentation is much better.

Comment: But images are not kept as JPEG data in memory. When you `CGContextDrawImage`, you draw a BMP.

Comment: I was just trying to provide a method for converting from a UIImage to a byte array.  It is going to be slower but just in case you wanted to modify the data before sending it up to the server.